# Are there any books which explain Indian cooking in terms of science?

Tags: indian-cuisine

My attempt to make a paneer curry taste similar to restaurant is turning into a mad goose chase. I've literally tried 100s of recipes shown on Google, YouTube, etc, but I'm not getting the taste similar to the ones sold in restaurant.

I'm thinking it's poor quality ingredients I buy, especially tomatoes. But I don't think that entirely explains it. Because, a restaurant I frequently visit has two chefs, one chef makes the paneer curry taste good, the other chef makes the curry taste so bad.

So how exactly do they get the taste, could it be because, as they prepare large quantities, the flavour gets intensified?

Or is it because of sophisticated cooking techniques with knowledge of chemistry of ingredients, like a science.

What science books are chefs made to study, where can I buy them? Does it explain how to prepare, how to cook, which to cook first, and at what stage ingredients have to be added?

The recipes posted on Internet for garam masala, etc seem to be by people who don't anything about cooking, they just seem to throw ingredients haphazardly and grind.

The restaurants seem to have mastered it to the level of science, so that they get the same taste every time. Where do these learn, what books do they study, where can I buy those books?

Comment: It's easy to make food taste good if you don't care about nutrition: more fat, more sugar.

Comment: The question was closable, but a small pointer: answers wouldn't have helped you anyway. "Books on food science", "Books from which professional chefs learn" and "A way for a hobby cook to start producing good curry" are typically three distinct things with very little overlap to each other.